# Facebook Graph How to get a concurrent session's public info?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering how to get either the uid or the public user info (name, pic) from a FB session that is not connected with my site. I'm noticing it in some of the social widgets and yelp is doing it too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271674/getting-a-visitors-facebook-info-without-app-permission-how-does-yelp-do-it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to partner with Facebook so that they enable [Instant Personalization](https://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/) for your website / application.